# Deleting the branch of a repository inside of Azure Devops Web UI

Tags: azure-devops

I'm working within the Azure Devops web interface, is there a screen developed to delete the branch of a repository?

Is the only option to do so through another tool such as the git command line interface?

Comment: If you have the correct permissions, a 'trash can' icon shows up on the same row as the branch, unless it is locked. Only the default branch cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have the correct permissions:

[image]

[image]